# surrounding selected text with parentheses (like Textmate)

Tags: javascript

I'd like the javascript and HTML for a `textarea` that surrounds text with parentheses, braces, brackets, and single- or double-quotes when the desired text is selected and one types the 'opening' (left) version of the brace, quote, paren, etc.

For example, if the textarea contains 'A quick brown fox jumped', and 'brown fox' is selected, and I then hit the left-brace key on my keyboard, 'brown fox' should then become surrounded by braces, and be unselected. The same goes for parens, single/double quotes, and brackets.

The solution should work in recent versions of Chrome, FF, and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this full solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var keyMap = {
                        '(': ')',
                        '[': ']',
                        '<': '>',
                        '{': '}',
                        '"': '"',
                        '\'': '\''
                    };

                    $('.editor').keypress(function(e){
                        if(this.selectionStart == this.selectionEnd)
                            return true;

                         e.preventDefault();

                         var txtCur = $(this).val();
                         var left = txtCur.substring(0, this.selectionStart);
                         var middle = txtCur.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd);
                         var right = txtCur.substring(this.selectionEnd);

                         var cur = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

                         if(keyMap[cur])
                            middle = cur + middle + keyMap[cur];
                         else
                            middle = cur;

                         var pos = (left+middle).length;
                         $(this).val(left+middle+right);
                         this.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);

                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea class="editor">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Search Google for how to get the selected range of text - you don't need the contents, just the start position and length. Then break up the string using `substr` into "before, between and after" parts, insert the parentheses and join the pieces together again.

If you've written code and are having real problems I'll be happy to help. Meanwhile, please read [this blog post denouncing the kind of attitude you're showing here](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).